# Loading external library in clojure

Tags: clojure

```
{:deps
  com.google.code.gson/gson {:mvn/version "2.9.0"}}
 }
```

in core.clj: evaluate

```
(ns core
  (:require [google.code.gson/gson :refer :all]
            )
  (:gen-class))
```

I get exception:
Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException

Call to clojure.core/ns did not conform to spec.

I just want to load gson into my namespace. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `com.google.code.gson/gson` is the library name, not the name of the namespace inside that library. Also, `:require` is for _Clojure_ libraries, not _Java_ libraries; for the latter you should use `:import` to pull in the specific Java classes you want to load; you'll need to read gson's docs to figure out the ones you want.

Comment: (Java doesn't have a concept of namespaces, so `:import` doesn't have an equivalent to `:refer :all`)

Answer (score 1):

Group/Artifact coordinates (what you are using to resolve dependencies;
e.g. `com.google.code.gson/gson`) are *not* related to what is *in*
those artifacts.  So you can not just require the artifact. You have to
require the namespaces of what is in them or more likely in this case
`import` the classes that are in them (it's a java library more likely
and not a Clojure library).

The error you get there is due to the `/` in the require.  And even if
you the needed `.` instead you will see an error, that no such namespace
exists.

Comment: Should (ns core
  (:import [google.code.gson gson])
  (:gen-class))

 work?

Comment: Is there a class called `gson` inside the package `google.code.gson`? I strongly doubt it, because it's not conventional to use lowercase class names. You have to check the docs/source of the library you are using and then work from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ns core
  (:gen-class))

(import [com.google.gson Gson])
```

seems to work.

But why do not need the **code** part in com.google.code.gson?

Comment: You should use `:import` inside the namespace instead.

Comment: You don't need the "**code** part" because that's not how gson's authors named the classes it contains. It's not a decision made by Clojure, it's a decision made by gson.